# What does +-? mean in the output of service

Tags: 14.04, services

I would like to know what does `+`, `-` and `?` mean in the output of 
`service --status-all`. For example:

```
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ + ]  atd
```